# Pentaho Data Integration, Insert / Update step to continue even after it finds some errors

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using this Insert / Update step in one my transformations,
I want this step to be completed even if there are some errors while inserting.

For example;

In one of the entries i get this error.

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`risk_module`.`customer`, CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_customer1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Inserting stops at this row.
But, I want it to continue even after it finds such errors.
Is it possible to do.
Please help me.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect the output of the `Insert/Update` step to a `Table Output` step, but when it gives you the pop up windows, don't select 'Main Output of step', select 'Error Handling of step'.

Then when the transform runs, rows that cause insert/error rows will end up where ever you direct your `Table Output` step. All others will be processed normally.